# how can I disable WCF Service Authentication using CustomBinding in code behind?

Tags: wcf, security, authentication, binding, udp

I am using CustomBinding (UdpBinding which I use microsoft wcf sample Udp sample). It is work when client and server is in same machine. I host service and I try to connect to service. It is timeout. How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You UDP traffic is lost somewhere in transition from the client to the server. It probably is a network issue you are having. Check the following:

1. Use WireShark to see the UDP packet leave the client machine and check that its destination is the server you have your service running on.
2. Make sure your firewall is not blocking your packet.
3. Check that your network infrastructure is able to route the UDP packets from the client to the server.
4. Also use WireShark to see if any UDP packets are entering on the server machine. Make sure the firewall is not blocking the packets.

That's the prolem with UDP. It is un *unreliable* protocol. The client will never know if it arrives at your destination.